# Return in parameter list

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am reading the source code of `Spark`, and I am not sure if I understand this line `readFunction: (PartitionedFile) => InputPartitionReader[T]`.

Questions:

1. So we can pass a method `readFunction` as a parameter to a case class?
2. Is there a terminology for this?
3. Are there any special motivations for this syntax?

   ```
   case class FileInputPartition[T](
   file: FilePartition,
   readFunction: (PartitionedFile) => InputPartitionReader[T],<-- This line
   ignoreCorruptFiles: Boolean = false,
   ignoreMissingFiles: Boolean = false)
   extends InputPartition[T] {
   override def createPartitionReader(): InputPartitionReader[T] = {
   val taskContext = TaskContext.get()
   val iter = file.files.iterator.map(f => PartitionedFileReader(f, 
   readFunction(f)))
   FileInputPartitionReader(taskContext, iter, ignoreCorruptFiles, 
   ignoreMissingFiles)
   }

   override def preferredLocations(): Array[String] = {
   FilePartitionUtil.getPreferredLocations(file)
   }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Scala functions are [first class objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function). It means that:

> the language supports passing functions as arguments to other functions, returning them as the values from other functions, and assigning them to variables or storing them in data structures

In this case constructor can take `Function1[PartitionedFile, InputPartitionReader[T]]`. There is nothing particularly unusual here and functions as arguments are ubiquitous in Scala, with the most prominent example of `collection` API.

And in fact this how the function is used here - to `map` over collection:

```
file.files.iterator.map(f => PartitionedFileReader(f, readFunction(f)))
```

This usage pretty much explains the motivation.